# creation of custom spring annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

Due to architecture constraints and possible misuse we decided not to use the Lombok plugin.

I want to create new custom annotation to do exactly what the @Getter, @Setter annotations do without using them from the Lombok plugin.
 I read the lombok source code and the documentation and there is use of some encapsulated properties which I am not sure how to implement myself.

I have already searched for some details and there is not something similar I found.  Is there a way to implement these annotations myself?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using Lombok, however if you can't there are alternatives. There is Immutables and AutoValue which have similar features that I'm aware of.  https://immutables.github.io/ or https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md

```
@Value.Immutable
```

or

```
 @AutoValue
```